# Nuxt/Vue App doesn't load on Github Pages or Route 53

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, amazon-route53

Update: I now have Github pages displaying the correct index file instead of the README file -- but the Express server endpoint is throwing a 404. This occurred because I switched my github workflow action to the following:

```html
# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Nuxt site to GitHub Pages
#
# To get started with Nuxt see: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation
#
name: Deploy Nuxt site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "manager=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/package.json" ]; then
            echo "manager=npm" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=ci" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Unable to determine packager manager"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "16"
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v2
        with:
          # Automatically inject router.base in your Nuxt configuration file and set
          # target to static (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-target/).
          #
          # You may remove this line if you want to manage the configuration yourself.
          static_site_generator: nuxt
      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            dist
            .nuxt
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuxt-build-${{ hashFiles('dist') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuxt-build-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}
      - name: Static HTML export with Nuxt
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} run generate
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          path: ./dist

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

If I can get the Github pages working correctly (because everything does work correctly locally) then I feel my Route53 host will work. Again, this is a nuxt Vue app with both a client and server code. So I need it hosted on a node server.

Here are my scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "nuxt --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
  },
```

Here's the *index.js* file in my server package:

```html
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}
const Post = require('./models/post');
const express = require('express');
const consola = require('consola');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const xss = require('xss-clean');


app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    })
  )
app.use(express.json())
app.use(xss());

// Import and set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

// Init Nuxt.js
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server;

const username = process.env.username;
const pwd = process.env.pwd;
const server = process.env.server;
const db = process.env.db;

const dbURI = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${pwd}@${server}/${db}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

async function start() {
    // Build only in dev mode
    if (config.dev) {
        const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
       await builder.build();
    } else {
        await nuxt.ready();
    }
    // Render every route with Nuxt.js
    app.use(nuxt.render);

    consola.ready({
        message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
        badge: true
    });
}

start();

mongoose
    .connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then((result) => {
        app.listen(port, host); // listen
        }
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get('/isAlive', async (req, res) => {
    res.send('i am alive');
});

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
    Post
        .find()
        .sort({createdAt: -1})
        .then((result) => {
            res.send(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
})

app.post(
    '/posts', 
    (req, res) => {
        const post = new Post({
            body: req.body.post.trim()
        });
        post
            .save()
            .then((result) => {
                res.send(result);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
);
```

And my *nuxt.conf.js* file:

```html
// import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

module.exports = {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,
  telemetry: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s',
    title: '',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/'
  },

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: false
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    loaders: {
      vue: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          audio: 'src'
        }
      }
    },
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          esModule: false
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

My Github Pages is displaying the README file. I get it, that's what it does by default, it hosts the content of the root of the repo which doesn't have an index.html but does have a README. Here's the root of my repo:

[image]

I commit my *.nuxt* and *dist* folders after running *nuxt generate* and *nuxt build* and I guess I thought that those files would be served from Pages and Route 53.

What happens is that Github deploys to Route 53 which now throws an error of 502 Bad Gateway.

I have deployed successfully, although it was almost 10 months ago, to both Pages and Route 53. Has something changed that I need to know about that's different with Nuxt (I'm using version 2.15.3) or Vue? Or can someone see where I'm going wrong?

FYI: I'm pushing to the *main* branch, not *master*. But commits from both still trigger a build. And here's my workflow yml file:

[image]

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: `nuxt build` is for `SSR` and `nuxt generate` is for `SSG`. As you may guess, you only need to use one, not both. Also, if you want to use SSG, I recommend Netlify or Vercel rather. You will have a far better time setting them up than with Github Pages or route 53.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I can see that nuxt generate is the way to go. Also, Github Pages and Route 53 were already working so I don't want to dump it and start s/thing new.

Comment: Github pages is a bad experience and I will not try to debug that one since it has too many drawbacks. As for AWS, a 502 indicates a configuration error. So you check on some dashboard or alike. Something expired or was probably deprecated. Not directly related to Nuxt. Try to run it locally to confirm, but that should just work IMO.

Comment: Quite a huge chunk of code for sure, try to narrow the issue down a bit IMO.